# VBA copy and paste from one worksheet to another worksheet base on specific headers

Tags: excel, vba, header, copy, paste

I just new to this VBA and have been trying myself by looking at YTube and I want to learn more. I want to copy and paste from one sheet to another sheet using their identical header name. The source worksheet has over 30 columns and lots of formula, text and date.

I want to transfer only 7 columns to the destination worksheet.The destination and source worksheets's header are on row 8.

I have the following code but using this code, it only copy and paste to column 1. I didn't get the rest, even though the header name is the same and i can't figure out what is wrong with this code.

I am expecting to copy and paste value using the matching headers and give me all data.

Any help please and thank you in advance.

```
Sub pullData()

Dim header_count As Integer
Dim row_count As Integer
Dim col_count As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet

Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Template")
Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Prior Month")

ws2.Activate

header_count = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A8", Range("A8").End(xlToRight)))
ws1.Activate
col_count = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A8", Range("A8").End(xlToRight)))
row_count = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A8", Range("A8").End(xlDown)))

For i = 1 To header_count
    j = 1
    Do While j <= col_count
        If ws2.Cells(1, j) = ws1.Cells(1, j).Text Then
            ws1.Range(Cells(1, j), Cells(row_count, j)).Copy
            ws2.Cells(1, j).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            j = col_count
        End If
        j = j + 1
    Loop
Next i

With ws2
    .Activate
    .Cells(1, i).Select
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Are you always setting j back to 1 in the outer loop and that is causing the problem?

Comment: You should read up on avoiding Select and Activate and adding sheet references to your code.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working version of your code:

```
Sub PullData()
    Dim template As Worksheet
    Dim priorMonth As Worksheet
    Dim priorMonthHeaderCount As Long
    Dim templateColCount As Long

    Set template = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Template")
    Set priorMonth = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Prior Month")    
    priorMonthHeaderCount = priorMonth.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    templateColCount = template.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    
    Dim priorMonthHeaderIndex As Long
    Dim templateColumnIndex As Long
    For priorMonthHeaderIndex = 1 To priorMonthHeaderCount
        For templateColumnIndex = 1 To templateColCount
            If priorMonth.Cells(1, priorMonthHeaderIndex) = template.Cells(1, templateColumnIndex) Then
                template.Columns(templateColumnIndex).Copy Destination:=priorMonth.Columns(priorMonthHeaderIndex)
                Exit For
            End If
        Next templateColumnIndex
    Next priorMonthHeaderIndex
End Sub
```

This was not working for you as expected because you wrote

`If ws2.Cells(1, j) = ws1.Cells(1, j).Text` instead of

`If ws2.Cells(1, i) = ws1.Cells(1, j).Text`

It may take you a minute to see the difference between the two. This is why giving meaningful names to your variables can be so helpful.

Some changes:

- Changed the `Do ... While` to a nested `For` loop for better readability
- Removed the `Activate` and `Select`, since they are not needed for this code
- Gave more descriptive variable names
- Changed  `j = col_count` to `Exit For` for better readability
- According to [ozgrid.com](https://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/SpeedingUpVBACode.htm#:%7E:text=%27By%2Dpasses%20the%20Clipboard), using the `Destination:=` argument in the `.Copy` method bypasses the Clipboard. Therefore you don't need to clear it and I was able to remove `Application.CutCopyMode = False`.

Answer (score 0):

### Copy Data Based on Headers

[image]

```vb
Sub PullData()
    
    ' Define constants
    
    Const SRC_SHEET As String = "Template"
    Const SRC_HEADER_ROW As Long = 8
    Const DST_SHEET As String = "Prior Month"
    Const DST_HEADER_ROW As Long = 8
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Reference the source ranges.
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Sheets(SRC_SHEET)

    Dim shrg As Range, sdrg As Range, srCount As Long

    With sws.UsedRange
        Set shrg = Intersect(sws.Rows(SRC_HEADER_ROW), .Cells)
        srCount = .Rows(.Rows.Count).Row - SRC_HEADER_ROW
        Set sdrg = shrg.Resize(srCount).Offset(1)
    End With
    
    ' Reference the destination ranges.
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Sheets(DST_SHEET)

    Dim dhrg As Range, ddrg As Range

    With dws.UsedRange
        Set dhrg = Intersect(dws.Rows(DST_HEADER_ROW), .Cells)
        Set ddrg = dhrg.Offset(1).Resize(srCount)
    End With
    
    ' Pull.
    
    Dim scIndexes: scIndexes = Application.Match(dhrg, shrg, 0)
    
    Dim scIndex, dc As Long
    
    For Each scIndex In scIndexes
        dc = dc + 1
        If IsNumeric(scIndex) Then
            ddrg.Columns(dc).Value = sdrg.Columns(scIndex).Value
        End If
    Next scIndex
    
    ' Inform.
    
    MsgBox "Data pulled.", vbInformation

End Sub
```